# Where are documented the required roles for Keycloak admin API endpoints?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

All the documentation for the Keycloak admin API I found so far is [this one](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/23.0.3/rest-api/). What I can tell for it is that there is some room for improvement :/ (for instance it is more reliable to inspect the payloads with Chrome debugging tools when manipulating the admin console than using "Definitions" from the doc).

The point I am most missing right now are the roles required for each endpoints. As this is not completely intuitive, I wonder if the access control for the various endpoints is documented somewhere.

For instance using a "service account" client granted with just `create-client` "client" role for a given realm was not enough to create a client in that realm. I had to grant it with either `admin` realm role (which I want to avoid as it is clearly too much) or a combination of all `*-client` "client" roles.